# Django admin: how to display number with fixed length?

Tags: django, django-admin

This is my model:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma


class Flow(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    
    def df_amount(self):
        return '{intcomma(abs(self.amount)):>12}'
    df_amount.admin_order_field = 'amount'
    df_amount.short_description = 'amount'
```

In `admin.py`,

```
@admin.register(Flow)
class FlowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'df_amount',
    )
```

For `amount=2800`, `print(self.df_amount())` gives `$    2,800.00`
but `$ 2,800.00` is displayed in the admin panel where the spaces in the middle were truncated to only one space, not as expected.

So my question is how to reserve the spaces in the middle of the string in admin panel? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`format_html(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) function,

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


@admin.register(Flow)
class FlowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'df_amount',
    )

    def df_amount(self, instance):
        return format_html(f'$ {instance.df_amount().replace(" ", "&nbsp;")}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw, the `&nbsp;` was read as html, hence literally not showing up. Please replace the `&` with `&amp;`.